# Bootstrap Typeahead results shift

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am not quite sure how I can fix this, because I don't want it to shift when I enter letters. 
http://ch1n3s3.ch.funpic.de/try.php
There you can see my problem demonstrated. Just enter A, B or C.

Do you have any possible solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the search is increasing once the li elements are shown, pushing the search to the left.  Add this css, which specifies a fixed width for the search.

```
.form-search{
   width: 195px;
}
```

Comment: it basically worked, but only without the sub nav. I fixed the demonstration. Thanks for the answer though. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @ChrisPalmerBreuer When I set the width, everything seemed to work fine, can you further explain the new issue?

Comment: the problem is that the sub navigation drops after I set the width. I uploaded it, so you could check it out. Thanks a ton for helping out, if I could give you reputation I toally would

Comment: I'm not sure that is being caused by the fixed width on search.  If the subnav is the black section with content "tab tab tab tab", it doesn't budge when i remove the width from the search.